# Accessibility issues for children elements of tablist

Tags: html, accessibility, axe

I am trying to solve the accessibility issue discovered by axe tools for tablist.

In our case tabs in a tablist are separated by the vertical separator with an appropriate role and aria-orientation. However the tool says that role=separator is not allowed to be inside of element with role=tablist.

> Ensures elements with an ARIA role that require child roles contain them

The code looks as following:

```
<div role="tablist" aria-orientation="horizontal">

<button id="tab-0" aria-controls="panel-0" type="button" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">One</button>

<div class="vertical-separator">
  <div class="tab-separator role="separator" aria-orientation="vertical"></div>
</div>

<button id="tab-1" aria-controls="panel-1" type="button" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false">Disabled</button>

</div>
```

What is a way to satisfy the accessibility rule?
As a tool's proposal there are two ways:

> Element has children which are not allowed (see related nodes)

> Element has no aria-busy="true" attribute

But none of them is fitting

Comment: I think you can just put role=none or role=presentation. You may even remove entirely the separator with aria-hidden=true, since it brings no value for screen reader users. I'm not fully sure though that there isn't any better, that's why I'm posting this as a comment rather than as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to nit-pick, one could argue that axe is wrong with that error.

The [tablist role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#tablist) says that "[Required Owned Elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#mustContain)" must have a role of [tab](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#tab). It does not really say that **only** tab roles can be children.

For example, the [spec for `<ul>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) says:

> **Content model:** 
> Zero or more `<li>` and script-supporting elements.

That is, it specifically says that child elements of a `<ul>` **must only be** `<li>` elements (or scripting elements).

The "[Required Owned Elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#mustContain)" section of roles is not as specific. It does not say that **only** certain child elements are allowed but rather, in order for a child element to be considered owned by the parent, it must have a specific role.

In this case, in order for a child element to be owned by the `tablist`, it must have a role of `tab`. If a child element does not have that role, then it's not considered owned by the tablist. Does that mean a tablist cannot have child elements without a tab role?  That's where it gets iffy. It doesn't really say that although I'm sure it's a good idea.

Even the URL for "Required Owned Elements" is called "*#mustContain*".  Meaning, it must contain a tab child.  But the URL is not called "*#must**Only**Contain*".

The [tablist pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tabs/) says:

> Each element that serves as a tab has role tab and is contained within the element with role tablist.

Again, this doesn't say that all child elements must be a tab, but only those child elements with a role of tab will be considered a tab and owned by the tablist.

When a tablist is surfaced to assistive technology, such as a screen reader, it will look at all the child elements of the tablist that have a role of tab and that will be the count of the number of tabs.  The screen reader will say "*[tab label], tab, 3 of 4*".  Any child that does not have a role of tab will not be included in that count.

Now, with all that being said, I would still encourage that all child elements have a role of tab, but I'm not sure it really breaks the rules if you don't.

In your particular case, it might be better to use CSS :after on the tab button to add a vertical separator rather than the separator being a separate DOM element.

The [tablist example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tabs/examples/tabs-manual/) in the design pattern has a gap between each tab button.  That gap is done with CSS on the button rather than a separate gap DOM element.