# How can the screenreader access/read the content in an accordion tabpanel?

Tags: accessibility, accordion

I've got the following code that has a single accordion element (for brevity. it would normally be more) in an open state. Screen readers do not seem to be able to read "My Copy", they just read the title.

However, if I put a fieldset with a form input in there, you can tab to the form input easily. What the hell am i doing wrong here? Why can't the screen reader tab to and read the copy?

```
<div class="js-accordion" aria-multiselectable="false" role="tablist">           
    <h2 class=""><button class="" role="tab" id="accordionznntk0bkn5d_tab1" aria-controls="accordionznntk0bkn5d_panel1" aria-selected="true" type="button" aria-expanded="true">
        My title
    </button></h2>
    <div class="js-accordion__panel" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="accordionznntk0bkn5d_tab1" id="accordionznntk0bkn5d_panel1">
        <div class="">
              <p>My copy </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking how to navigate using a screen reader. <kbd>TAB</kbd> is certainly one way to navigate but only one of many ways.  If you're on a PC and using NVDA or JAWS, try the down arrow key. It essentially walks every element in the DOM (that isn't hidden).

So from your `My title` button, you can press the down arrow and you should hear *"My copy"*.

- [JAWS keyboard shortcuts](https://www.freedomscientific.com/training/jaws/hotkeys/)
- [NVDA keyboard shortcuts](https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html#SingleLetterNavigation)

Comment: Oh great, thanks!! Ok, but other than that, the above HTML all looks correct, right? Nothing missing?
On Windows it's throwing an error in the inspector code view saying that role="tab" must be surrounded by an element with role="tablist" which it is! It's confusing the hell out of me!

Comment: Well, that would be another question (; But yes, everything looks good, ARIA seems to be used quite well. Both `tab` and `tabpanel` are contained in `tablist`, so that’s ok. But we don’t see the code for the other tabs, so it’s hard to say whether the logic is respected. I would assume it is. Also, [focus _should_ be managed](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#managingfocus) in a tablist, meaning that only one tab can receive focus via _tab_, then f.e. arrow keys allow selecting another tab.

Comment: @Andy I mean, the rest of the tabs are just the same as above but expanded & selected false! I'm just utterly perplexed with this. Why is the inspector reporting that error and why in Chrome on windows does hitting return not open the tab. So many questions!

Comment: The first might be due to a bug in inspector. Which browser’s inspector is that? For the enter that’s weird, we’d need an interactive code sample to reproduce your issue and help with that.

Comment: First, I agree with @Andy that the question of whether the code looks correct is another question. I was answering the original navigation question. Second, the code inspector is not going to complain about your code. I assume you're using a plugin scanning tool like [axe](https://www.deque.com/axe/) or [wave](https://wave.webaim.org/extension/) and it's showing an error. And lastly, I've seen these scanning tools **incorrectly** flag a `role="tab"` if it was not an **immediate** child of a `role="tablist"`. The spec doesn't say it has to be an immediate child, just "contained" within...(cont)

Comment: ...(cont). You can see more details regarding the tablist structure in my answer to "[Accessibility issues for children elements of tablist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75798750/accessibility-issues-for-children-elements-of-tablist/75804539#75804539)". When I look at your code, you have an `<H2>` between the `role="tablist"` and the `role="tab"`. That's allowed but it means the `role="tab"` is now a *grandchild* of the `role="tab"` instead of a *child*. Some scanning tools will incorrectly flag that as an error. I recommend the tab be a direct child but technically it's not required.

Comment: Finally, and this is why your second question should be a real question instead of a comment, because now we're trying to answer your question using the limited space in a comment which requires multiple comments, take a look at the [tab pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tabs/).